# What are the performance implications of these C# features?

Tags: xna, c#

I have been designing a component-based game library, with the overall intention of writing it in C++ (as that is my forte), with Ogre3D as the back-end.  Now that I am actually ready to write some code, I thought it would be far quicker to test out my framework under the XNA4.0 framework (somewhat quicker to get results/write an editor, etc).  However, whilst I am no newcomer to C++ or C#, I *am* a bit of a newcomer when it comes to doing things the "XNA" way, so to speak, so I had a few queries before I started hammering out code:

1. I read about using arrays rather than collections to avoid performance hits, then also read that this was not entirely true and that if you enumerated over, say, a concrete `List<>` collection (as opposed to an `IEnumerable<>`), the enumerator is a value-type that is used for each iteration and that there aren't any GC worries here.  The article in question was back in 2007.  Does this hold true, or do you experienced XNA developers have real-world gotchas about this?  Ideally I'd like to go down a chosen route before I do too much.
2. If arrays truly are the way to go, no questions asked, I assume when it comes to resizing the array, you copy the old one over with new space?  Or is this off the mark?  Do you attempt to never, ever resize an array?  Won't the GC kick in for the old one if this is the case, or is the hit inconsequential?
3. As the engine was designed for C++, the design allows for use of lambdas and delegates.  One design uses the `fastdelegate` library which is the fastest possible way of using delegates in C++.  A more flexible, but slightly slower approach (though hardly noticeable in the world of C++) is to use C++0x lambdas and `std::function`.  Ideally, I'd like to do something similar in XNA, and allow delegates to be used.  Does the use of delegates cause any significant issues with regard to performance?
4. If there are performance considerations with regards to delegates, is there a difference between:

   ```
   public void myDelegate(int a, int b);
   private void myFunction(int a, int b)
   {
   }

   event myDelegate myEvent;

   myEvent += myFunction;
   ```

vs:

```
    public void myDelegate(int a, int b);

    event myDelegate myEvent;

    myEvent += (int a, int b) => { /* ... */ };
```

Sorry if I have waffled on a bit, I prefer to be clear in my questions. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please separate your questions into individual questions.

Comment: Whilst not intending for it to be a discussion point, I believe all points are pertinent together as stated rather than cluttering the board with 4 individual questions.  Also, whilst I have brought up 4 individual points, If there are any gotchas "as a whole", I thought it best they be kept together in a single place.

Comment: There are at least two completely different questions, one about the performance of different sequences and one about the performance of different delegation schemes. All four questions are also not really related to game programming beyond the fact you appear to be making a game. (None are actually about XNA, for example.)

Comment: -1 and voted to close; I agree with Joe. This should be multiple questions, some of which are more appropriate for StackOverflow. We'd prefer that the site (which is not a discussion board) be "cluttered" with different questions as it makes them easier to locate.

Comment: Perhaps a way to re-state the question to fit gamedev would be "What are the most common performance issues you stumble on in XNA using C#?" though you should also state a target platform/device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the only major performance issue to be aware of in C# that is different to what you have to be aware of in C++, is the garbage collector. Simply don't allocate memory during your main game loop and you'll be fine. [Here is a blog post that goes into detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana.aspx).

Now to your questions:

**1)** If a framework collection iterator could be implemented as a value-type (not creating garbage), then it usually (always?) has been. You can safely use `foreach` on, for example, `List<>`.

You can verify if you are allocating in your main loop by using the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273).

**2)** Use `List`s instead of arrays. They'll handle the resizing for you. You should use the `Capacity` property to pre-allocate enough space before you start gameplay to avoid GC issues. Using arrays you'd just have to implement all this functionality yourself - ugly!

The GC kicks in on allocations (not when memory becomes free). On Xbox 360 it kicks in for every 1MB allocated and is very slow. On Windows it is a bit more complicated - but also doesn't have such a huge impact on performance.

**3)** C# delegates are pretty damn fast. And faster than most people expect. They are about on-par with method calls on interfaces. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082735/performance-of-calling-delegates-vs-methods) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209055/c-sharp-delegate-performance-in-xna-game) are questions that provide more detials about delegate performance in C#.

I couldn't say how they compare to the C++ options. You'd have to measure it.

**4)** No. I'm fairly sure this code will produce identical IL. You could disassemble it and check, or profile it, though.

I might add - without checking myself - I suspect that having an `event myDelegate` will be slower than a plain `myDelegate` if you don't need all the magic of `event`.

Comment: Thank you for your concise response, I appreciate it.

Comment: For point #2, in the engines I have come across in this industry, 2 of them didn't even have a counterpart to List. The others rarely used it (mostly in editors, where performance doesn't matter so much). This is because lists are very slow and cache incoherent (especially on consoles). When designing a game, you should know precisely what your maximum limit of anything is, and that is the allocation you make for your array. There are very few things where the size of the array will fluctuate so much that a list will be required in game development (objects in a level editor for example)

Comment: @Samaursa Are you thinking of linked-lists? The .NET `List<>` class is essentially a fancy array, with practically identical performance and memory characteristics. It is equivalent to the C++ `std::vector`.

Comment: @AndrewRussell: I did assume it was `linked-lists`. Thanks for the pointing that out. Their name selection is interesting in this case as it can cause this confusion. So a `List<>` is similar to std::vector and `LinkedList<>` is then similar to `std::list<>` (why would they not keep the same naming convention?)

Comment: Because "they" are not the same group of people.

Comment: @JoshPetrie: Sure, but sticking to a standard means less pain for developers switching (or switching back and forth). Similar to how most 3D CAD packages follow similar set of rules for basic things.