# What more can I do to improve performance on this class?

Tags: c#, performance, xna, 2d

I'm currently developing a 2D game with C#/XNA. The game's core feature are bullets with vastly different behaviors (it will be kind of a bullet hell game).
Updating all the bullets can take quite some time since they can be infinitely complex with their behaviors. And all of them have to do 1 collision check.
Originally I just stored them in a List and updated and drew all of them, removing inactive bullets from the list each frame.
This however quickly proved to slow the game down when there where 8k bullets on the screen, so I decided to implement multithreading and using LINQ to help performance.

Thing is it's still slowing down at around 16k bullets. I was told I could achieve up to 7 MILLION active bullets if I did it right, so I'm not satisfied with 16k...

Is there anything else I could do to improve performance here?

Additional information before code: My bullets have fields for velocity, direction, angular velocity, acceleration, a speedlimit and a Behavior.
The only special thing as mentioned is the behavior. It can modify any of the bullets fields at any time or spawn more bullets and even plant itself in them, therefore I'm having a hard time applying a Data-Driven Solution and just storing all these fields in arrays instead of having a list of bullets.

```
internal class BulletManager : GameComponent
{
    public static float CurrentDrawDepth = .82f;
    private readonly List<Bullet> _bullets = new List<Bullet>();
    private readonly int _processorCount;
    private int _counter;
    private readonly Task[] _tasks; 

    public BulletManager(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
        _processorCount = VariableProvider.ProcessorCount;
        _tasks = new Task[_processorCount];
    }

    public void ClearAllBullets()
    {
        _bullets.Clear();
    }

    public void AddBullet(Bullet bullet)
    {
        _bullets.Add(bullet);
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (StateManager.GameState != GameStates.Ingame &&
            (StateManager.GameState != GameStates.Editor || EngineStates.GameStates != EEngineStates.Running))
            return;

        var bulletCount = _bullets.Count;
        var bulletsToProcess = bulletCount / _processorCount;

        //Split up the bullets to update among all available cores using Tasks and a lambda expression
        for (var i = 0; i < _processorCount; ++i )
        {
            var x = i;
            _tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                                       {
                                           for(var j = bulletsToProcess * x; j < bulletsToProcess * x + bulletsToProcess; ++j)
                                           {
                                               if (_bullets[j].Active)
                                                    _bullets[j].Update();
                                           }
                                       });
        }

        //Update the remaining bullets (if any)
        for (var i = bulletsToProcess * _processorCount; i < bulletCount; ++i)
        {
            if (_bullets[i].Active)
                _bullets[i].Update();
        }
        //Wait for all tasks to finish
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks);

        //This is an attempt to reduce the load per frame, originally _bullets.RemoveAll(s => !s.Active) ran every frame.
        ++_counter;
        if (_counter != 300) return;
        _counter = 0;
        _bullets.RemoveAll(s => !s.Active);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        if (StateManager.GameState != GameStates.Ingame && StateManager.GameState != GameStates.Editor) return;

        spriteBatch.DrawString(FontProvider.GetFont("Mono14"), _bullets.Count.ToString(), new Vector2(100, 20),
                               Color.White);

        //Using some LINQ to only draw bullets in the viewport
        foreach (var bullet in _bullets.Where(bullet => Camera.ViewPort.Contains(bullet.CircleCollisionCenter.ToPoint())))
        {
            bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);
            CurrentDrawDepth -= .82e-5f;
        }
        CurrentDrawDepth = .82f;
    }
}
```

Comment: "16k bullets": Have less bullets!!! '-)

Comment: I'd try and reduce the number of bullets as @Jon says, even if you draw duplicates (new Pos, old Pos) to give the impression of more.

Comment: Have you run a profiler against it? What exactly in the class is it getting hung up on?

Comment: I would also try drawing all bullets, the graphics card should be better than the CPU at culling.

Comment: @Jon sure, actual gameplay will probably cap out at around max 8k bullets, but I want to add more systems (AI for example) and don't want to run into a performance bottleneck because of the bullets. Also I'm still learning aspects of programming and think this would help me learn new concepts.

Comment: What situation in a game could there be 16000 bullets on the screen at once?

Comment: @Charles [Bullet Hell](http://www.giantbomb.com/bullet-hell/92-321/) games are noted for having thousands of bullets on the screen at once.

Comment: @thed: interesting... looking at some screenshots, I can imagine a few thousand bullets now. Hard to wrap my head around even 8k though.

Comment: Posting the bullet.Update might be a good idea?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that LINQ can generate a lot of garbage, which is a big no-no in XNA games.

Comment: Also: this is a game-optimisation question and really belongs on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewRussell, not so sure about that...  it's a grey area.  I asked for some XNA performance questions on gamedev, and it got migrated here because of a unanimous vote of "general performance" query.  I like to think these kinds of questions are not *too* localized to be inadmissable here.

Comment: @Moo-Juice If it was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7799803/165500), then it was more of a C# performance question than a game performance question. It was borderline. I'd personally have left it, because the context *is* important. The performance requirements - and therefore answers - are different for a game vs (for example) a web app.

Comment: @AndrewRussell, and I'd agree with you on that.  Yes, it was borderline, but also pertinent to games. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow. There is a lot wrong with that code you posted (and possibly the code you didn't post). Here is what you need to do to improve performance, roughly in descending order of importance/necessity:

**Measure performance.** At the very basic level a frame-rate counter (or, better yet, a frame-time counter). You want to check that you are making things better.

**Don't allocate memory during your game loop.** The best way to check if you are is to use the [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273). While you may not be using `new` (to allocate `class` types, `structs` are ok), it would not surprise me if much of that LINQ is allocating memory behind-the-scenes.

Note that `ToString` will allocate memory. There are allocation-free ways (using `StringBuilder`) to draw numbers if you need them.

[This article gives more info.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana.aspx)

**Don't use LINQ.** LINQ is easy and convenient and absolutely not the fastest or most memory-efficient way to manipulate collections.

**Use a data-driven approach.** The key idea behind a data-driven approach is that you maintain cache-coherency ([more info](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/853/c-low-level-optimization-tips/870#870)). That is: all your `Bullet` data is stored linearly in memory. To do this, make sure `Bullet` is a `struct` and you store them in a `List<Bullet>`. This means that when one `Bullet` gets loaded into the CPU cache, it brings others along with it (memory is loaded into cache in large blocks), reducing the time the CPU spends waiting for memory to load.

To remove bullets quickly, overwrite the one you are removing with the last bullet in the list, then remove the last element. This allows you to remove elements without copying most of the list.

**Use `SpriteBatch` with a mind for performance.** Do a separate batch of sprites (`Begin()/End()` block) for your bullets. Use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` - it is by far the fastest mode. Doing a sort (as implied by your `CurrentDrawDepth`) is slow! Ensure all your bullets are using the same texture (use a texture atlas if necessary). Remember that batching is only a performance improvement if consecutive sprites share a texture. ([More info](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game/9289#9289))

If you are using `SpriteBatch` well, then it will *probably* be faster to draw all of your sprites and then let the GPU cull them if they are off-screen.

(Optional) **Maintain a different list for each behaviour**. This reduces the amount of branching in your code and could potentially make the code itself (ie: instructions, not data) more cache-coherent. Unlike the above points, this will only give a small performance improvement, so only implement it if you need to.

*(NOTE: Beyond this point these changes are difficult to implement, will make your code harder to read, and could even make it slower. Only implement these if absolutely necessary and you are measuring performance.)*

(Optional) **Inline your code.** Once you start getting into the many-thousands of bullets, you may need to inline your code (remove method calls) to squeeze out even more performance. The C# compiler doesn't inline, and the JIT only does it a little bit, so you need to inline by-hand. Method calls includes things like the `+` and `*` operators you might use on vectors - inlining these will improve performance.

(Optional) **Use a custom shader.** If you want even more performance than simply using `SpriteBatch`, write a custom shader that takes your `Bullet` data and calculates as much as possible on the GPU.

(Optional) **Make your data even smaller and (if possible) immutable.** Store your initial conditions (position, direction, time-stamp) in your `Bullet` struct. Then use the basic [equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) to calculate the *current* position/velocity/etc only as you need them. You can often get these calculations for "free" - as you probably have unused CPU time while it is waiting for memory.

If your data is immutable, then you can avoid transferring it onto the GPU each frame! (If you are adding/removing bullets, you'll have to update it on the GPU on those frames, though).

If you implemented all of these items, I imagine you probably could get up to 7 million bullets on a good machine. Although that would probably leave little CPU time left over for the rest of your game.

Comment: Spoken like a true c programer! (And I say this in a good performance-savvy way). Seriously thought, major props on the completeness of this answer. However, I might suggest using an array, rather than a list, to store bullets, as I believe you may have meant to say. See the "use data driven approach" paragraph.

Comment: by far the best answer. Exactly what I'm looking for! I'm basicly still a newborn in programming (started back in march this year) and trying to use everything new I learn (LINQ/Lambdas being the fotm this month). I didn't know LINQ would be bad for performance. I'm not sure about the spritebatch sort thing, won't overlapping bullets sometimes flicker if I don't sort them? I will try bullets as a struct, too bad structs can't inherit from other classes. I've learned so much form this answer, thank you again! @xixonia Lists internally use an Array and without them I would probably be lost =p

Comment: oh wow, CLR Profiler showed something I didn't expect: in roughly a minute of gameplay I create 32 mio. (roughly 650mb of data) new instances of a struct I use to handle coordinates in my TileEngine. Wouldn't it have been for this answer I'd probably never had stumbled upon that. Also I find it hard to wrap my head around the idea of not using new in my game loop, how else would I be able to create new bullets and attach new instances of time critical behaviors to them (like "change state after 2 seconds", those must be created on a per-bullet basis)

Comment: @xixonia the C# `List<>` type is equivalent to the C++ `std::vector`. Confusing, I know.

Comment: @xNidhogg If you use `Deferred` they will simply draw in the same order as you send them (so in the order they are created, generally). The only issue with the order changing is if you implement my "fast delete" trick and order is important in that case. Probably the first alternative you should use in place of inheritance is probably a `switch` statement. You could also consider a member delegate on the `struct` (it could be fast enough). **Note that `new` on a `struct` type is ok**, it's `new` on a `class` type that allocates heap memory (I added a note and link for this to my answer).

Comment: @Andrew Russell, My point was to use a fixed size array, and access it directly... But now I'm questioning if that's worth anything, simply because that's what the List<T> implementation does internally.

Comment: @AndrewRussell I've implemented all non optional points on your list (except the quick removal check for inactive bullets) and can now run 32k active bullets at 60 fps. Thank you again, I learned a lot today about memory management and optimization.

Comment: @xixonia: It's almost always best to use `List` and set its `Capacity` to pre-allocate enough space. Same effect as an array but much easier to manage. @xNidhogg: You're welcome :)

Comment: @AndrewRussell, twas late when I posted. I actually did some testing among using a T[] vs List<T> vs LinkedList<T> a while back. Adding, Removing, and Iterating over the collections. I even Inserted and Removed randomly (as linked lists are suppose to be good at this), and List<T> *always* won, especially when pre-setting the MaxLength. Perhaps .NET's LinkedList implementation is not so good?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris w.r.t. LinkedList vs List: If List allocates enough space initially it runs faster than LinkedList because LinkedList has to allocate this memory on the fly. While both are constant time, List will be faster since the memory is already allocated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Profile it and see where are hotspots
2. I doubt that using Tasks give you performance boost. Actually they could even slow down your game.
3. How many inactive bullets you have? Maybe removing them at start of game loop will improve performance a bit.

Comment: Tasks definitely grant a performance boost, before them it updated the bullets one at a time on one core, now it updates in parallel using all available cores on the machine. Inactive bullets were once cleaned up every frame, with the "only cleanup every 300 frames"-rule I have ca 200-500 inactive bullets max.

Comment: I would say, that you should try to optimize Bullet.Update() method. You call it 16K times, so even small performance gains could have huge impact on your games overall performance.

Comment: I agree on profiling. Maybe you haven't done a correct job on sharing materials and shaders and your Draw call is probably the heaviest of them all. http://code.google.com/p/nprof/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you removing inactive bullets?

I think this type of thing is often times solved by the concept of having a "pool" - maybe I'm missing something from your code, but it seems like you already have a concept of active, so why remove an inactive one to then create A NEW bullet which will at some point be removed again to be handled by GC.  Just reuse an inactive bullet.

Also, I can't tell you how much it hurts, but the usage of ToString() in your draw 30 times a second generates garbage to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

If the bullets' `Update()` methods are a bottleneck (make sure you do as @PiRX suggests and use a profiler first to find bottlenecks), you could either:

a) Only update the visible bullets each frame, and update the invisible bullets less frequently.

b) Simplify the update process: say, the bullet only executes its specific (time-consuming) behavior every 10 frames (every 0.5 seconds, whatever), and does some simple thing (like flying straight) rest of the time.

Both suggestions are a tradeoff between performance and accuracy of course.

Comment: Sadly since this is the core mechanic of the game, accuracy is key, so sloppy updating outside of the screen or in general could ruin player experience (unexpected behaviors)

Answer (score 0):

At least for bullets offscreen (or offscreen by a margin) you could replace the entire use of a bullet by checking when it's fired against what it should hit and sending a delayed message to the target of the hit that it's been hit by a bullet in N time. Then, the delayed message replaces the entire UPDATE calculations of those bullets and still applies damage.

Answer (score 0):

profiling is the best tool to find bottlenecks, as others alrady pointed out.
it's critical that `Update()` method is as optimized as it can be.

i'd also try and refactor the nested `for` cycles to reduce the number of iterations, like this (untested, off the top of my head code following):

```
_tasks.ForEach(i=>
{
 i.Factory.StartNew(()=>
 {
  _bullets.Where(j=> _bullets.IndexOf(j)%_tasks.IndexOf(i)==0 && j.Active).Update();
 }
}
);
```